# JQuery script with html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these files in the same folder:

- index.html
- style.css
- script.js

I want the nav#menu be nav#menu.sticky on top when I scroll. It should be like http://iconmonstr.com/ but nothing. I only know html and css.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Slogan</h2>
</header>
<nav id="menu">
</nav>
<section id="main-section">
</section>
<footer id="main-footer">
  © 2014 Copyright
</footer>
```

style.css

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
} 

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

#main-header {
  background: #08c;
  color: #fff;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu {
  background: red;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#main-section {
  border: 0.1em solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
  height: 1000px;
}

#main-footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menu = $("#menu");
  var pos = menu.position();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= pos.top) {
      menu.addClass("sticky");
    } else {
      menu.removeClass("sticky"); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: <script src="script.js"></script>

Comment: What do you mean "there's no relationship?"

Comment: The script doesn't work and in the developer tools of Firefox and Chrome in the section Javascript I don't see anything.

Comment: If you open page source and click on this "script.js" link, can you open js code?

Comment: Yes I can. But the code doesn't work.

Comment: There you go, you have your "relationship". Now you must check your JS code for errors. It would be nice if you post your HTML and JS code in the question.

Comment: By asking this question it means that you need more work on understanding how webpages work.

Comment: “Doesn't work” is not a problem description. [Do some debugging.](http://devtoolsecrets.com/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in this community and yesterday I was very tired. Now the post should be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using jQuery in `script.js` but you don't include the library.
2. You have malformed html code.

Try following code. It's working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="main-header">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Slogan</h2>
</header>
<nav id="menu">
</nav>
<section id="main-section">
</section>
<footer id="main-footer">
  © 2014 Copyright
</footer>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've changed?

- I've added `body` and `head` tags,
- I've put `script` which include jQuery from CDN in `head` tag but you can include this just before including your script and it can be loaded locally, not from CDN,
- I've move your `script` tag to the end because it's generally good practice. Briefly speaking page is rendered faster.

In addition, you wrote "The script doesn't work and in the developer tools of Firefox and Chrome in the section Javascript I don't see anything.". You should see in the console tab in Chrome: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

On the future: you should paste the code much earlier.

old:

Try this:

```
<script src="script.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Information for downvoters:
in HTML 4.x type attribute should be specified. In html5 is optional.

Comment: The "type" attribute is not necessary, and in fact is prone to error.

Comment: @Pointy wrong. The "type" attribute is required by xhtml and html < 5. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html

Comment: @dfsq when did I say that it was the reason OP has troubles?

Comment: @ElGavilan It's required by the spec, but not by any browser. There is no practical alternative to "application/javascript", and it will certainly not fix any problems the OP is having since all browsers default to JavaScript and have done so for ages. Simple misspellings in the type value cause all sorts of problems, and it's just of no practical benefit to anybody. But if you find following specs (and programming in HTML4 or XHTML) valuable, then Live Long and Prosper :)

Comment: I agree and I waited for OP feedback and OP wrote "Ok, thanks. I found a typo in my code, sorry :)", so the problem seems to be out of date now ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

in HTML document, you create a "relationship" (browser loads JS and parses it accordingly)

Same goes for CSS files. If they are in same page, they can interact (you can set CSS classes by JS on elements)

Answer (score 0):

Beginner gave an example of how to provide function to your javascript file.
When adding files to your html source, you must use html syntax.

```
<script src="script.js">
/**
 * Additional code may even go here
 */
</script>
```

Follows this syntax.
When adding the css file you'll want to continue to use html syntax as well.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```